# OpenVINO GPU performance optimization

Tags: c++, computer-vision, inference, openvino

I'm trying to speed up the inference on a people counter application, in order to use the GPU I've set the inference engine configuration setting as described:

```
device_name = "GPU"
ie.SetConfig({ {PluginConfigParams::KEY_CONFIG_FILE, "./cldnn_global_custom_kernels/cldnn_global_custom_kernels.xml"} }, device_name);
```

and loading the network on the inference engine I've set the target device like described below:

```
CNNNetwork net = netReader.getNetwork();

TargetDevice t_device = InferenceEngine::TargetDevice::eGPU; 

network.setTargetDevice(t_device);

const std::map<std::string, std::string> dyn_config = { { PluginConfigParams::KEY_DYN_BATCH_ENABLED, PluginConfigParams::YES } };

ie_.LoadNetwork(network,device_name, dyn_config);
```

but the inference engine use the CPU yet, and this slow down the inference time. There is a way to use the Intel GPU at maximum power to do inference on a particular network? I'm using the person-detection-retail-0013 model.

Thank's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you meant person-detection-retail-0013? Because I haven't found pedestrian-detection-retail-013 in open_model_zoo repo.

This might be expected that you see a slowdown while using GPU. The network, you tested, has the following layers as part of the network topology: PriorBox, DetectionOutput . Those layers are executed on CPU as documentation says: https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_docs_IE_DG_supported_plugins_CL_DNN.html
I have a guess that this may be the reason of the slowdown.

But to be 100% percent sure I would suggest to run benchmark_app tool to do bench-marking of the model. This tool can print detailed performance information about each layer. It should help to shed light what is the real root cause of the slowdown. More information about benchmark_app can be found here: https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_inference_engine_samples_benchmark_app_README.html

PS: Just a piece of advice regarding usage of IE API. `network.setTargetDevice(t_device);` - setTargetDevice is a deprecated method. It is enough to set a device using `LoadNetwork` like in your example: `ie_.LoadNetwork(network,device_name, dyn_config);`

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thank's. Now I've understand more clearly how to improve the inference performance on a intel cpu and gpu.